# Resize 2D array of integers (correlating to an image) to a specific size?

Tags: c++, arrays, image, vector

I have a 2D array like below:

```
255 255 255 255 255
255 128 128 128 255
255 128 255 255 255
255 128 128 128 255
255 255 255 255 255
```

The numbers above represent the RGB values of an image (R = G = B, a greyscale image). In this case it's a 5x5px image of the letter "C".

I want to resize this 5x5 array to some other dimensions, keeping aspect ratio. It's simple to convert to, say, a 20x20 array, as 1 array element is embiggened 2x in width and in height:

```
255

becomes

255 255
255 255
```

But what if I want an arbitrary size, say 32x32? What methods do image processing programs use to resize images? To emphasize: the aspect ratio remains the same.

To clarify: I need only scale a 2D array and keep some fidelity. I'm not working with images although it appears so, but using the concepts of image scaling might be useful(?).

Comment: Resizing an "array" is simple, the problem is the *scaling*. However, scaling an image is a well-known and also long solved problem and if you search for algorithms to scale images you will find *many* alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest route to go is nearest neighbor sampling. Plenty of tutorials around for this:

http://tech-algorithm.com/articles/nearest-neighbor-image-scaling/

Nearest neighbor can be used to scale an image (after resizing) to any size. so a `10x10` image could become a `50x34` image for example. But it will look stupid ...

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways that you can resize an image, more commonly known as *interpolation* or *decimation* (if you're upsizing or downsizing, respectively) in image processing applications. [Boost GIL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/gil/doc/index.html) has exactly what you're looking for. Otherwise, you can try to rewrite your own interpolation functions. In your case, there's no point to re-invent the wheel and should look into Boost.